# What might be happening if I release object, after releasing pool that object belongs to?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool

I am asking just logical question. Will object be released from memory if I release pool first and then release the object ? For example, here is my code snippet:

---

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(setImage) withObject:nil];
```

---

```
-(void)setImage
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];

    NSString *strUrl = @"--some URL--";

    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]];
    UIImage *myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

    [pool release];
    [imageData release];
}
```

Assume that the code snippet executes under non-ARC environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fine as you never added the imageData object to the autorelease pool, so the pool won't release it. If you had added the imageData object to the autorelease pool like this:

```
[[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strUrl]] autorelease];
```

The extra release would be an overrelease and your app may crash.
It looks like you've leaked `myImage` as this is never released.

Comment: How will it be over-released if I use autorelease in my code snippet? Because, pool is responsible for sending release message. But, in my case I release object after the pool has released itself. Correct me if I understood something wrong.

Comment: If you add `autorelease` to `imageData` then when you create it it will have a retain count of 1, when the autorelease pool releases `imageData`'s retain count will decrement and it will be dealloced. If you then try and release `imageData` you will get a crash. If you add `autorelease` to `myImage` it will work fine.

Comment: Ok, so when execution comes to _[imageData release]_, imageData object will not been found and causing crash.

Answer (score 1):

when you call `[pool release];` immediate deallocation wont happen to the autorelease objects that are added to the pool. So when you explicitly call `release` your imageData's reference count would reduce by 1. When pool releases either application would crash with deallocated instance or message sent to nil object.